# How to make a very simple executable (.exe) file?

Tags: windows

My goal is to run a *VBScript* file (.vbs) from an executable file (.exe) located in the same directory "E:\". What would be the simplest way to make the executable file?

I won't use something similar to "BAT to EXE Converter" or "VBS to EXE" because they're creating a file in the TMP folder, and I don't want that, it's not a simple way to open a file: the application could simply open the .vbs file already created i nstead of creating, opening and deleting a batch file that would start the .vbs file.

Why do I ask this? E: is a CD drive (I store data in it by making ISO files and mounting them). I want a .vbs file to run once the CD is inserted to a PC so I made the autorun.inf file but the problem is that it can only open a .exe file, it doesn't work when I type `open=launch.vbs`

Comment: You can always use AutoHotkey or the like for stuff like this.

Answer (score 5):

You should be able to trigger batch files (.bat) from autorun.inf. Then, script the batch file to [run your VBS file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11899730/running-vbscript-from-batch-file).

Comment: How to run the batch file in background?

Comment: I don't think that is possible through autorun.inf, but you should be able to achieve it using multiple BAT files. Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/411247/running-a-cmd-or-bat-in-silent-mode)

Answer (score 2):

To start a script, you should pass the specified script file contents to the registered script engine. 
You can run either of Windows Script Host engine versions by typing `wscript.exe` or `cscript.exe` (followed at least script name) at a command prompt.

In your case, you could use fully qualified path of choosen WSH engine at `open` entry in your [Autorun.inf file](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144200(v=vs.85).aspx).

Or you could use the `shellexecute` entry instead:

```
[AutoRun]
shellexecute="launch.vbs"
UseAutoPlay=1
```

Comment: I want my cd to be universal, and autoplay 2 is not always available, but I answered my own question